# geckodriver executable need to be in path

Tags: selenium, web, web-crawler, screen-scraping, geckodriver

```html
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "social_mapper.py", line 1149, in <module>
    peoplelist = fill_instagram(peoplelist)
  File "social_mapper.py", line 382, in fill_instagram
    InstagramfinderObject = instagramfinder.Instagramfinder(showbrowser)
  File "/root/social_mapper/modules/instagramfinder.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=firefoxprofile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

I have no idea in which file i need to set the executable path for geckodriver as there are many